# Railsのテンプレート中に記述したJavascriptを読み込み時に実行させない方法

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Railsのテンプレート内に記述したJavascript文を、レンダリング時に実行されないようにしたいと考えています。

現在は、Javascriptの仕様なのか、以下のようなソースコードがある時、テンプレートがレンダリングされた時に、if文内でRubyを用いて書いた処理が実行されてしまいます。

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
$("#<%= id %> .button").click(function()
{
    if ("<%= id %>"== $(this).parents().attr("id") )
    {
        <% puts "クリック時のみ動作させたい処理" %>
    }
});
</script>
```

実現したい処理としては、テンプレートのレンダリング時にはif文内の処理を行わせず、buttonクラスをクリックした時のみ処理させたいと思っております。

良い方法があれば、ご教授頂ければと思っております。宜しくお願いします。

Comment: 念のためお聞きしますが、クリック時に行いたい処理はRubyで書かれた `puts "クリック時のみ動作させたい処理"` なのか、Javascriptで書かれた `クリック時のみ動作させたい処理` なのか、どちらでしょうか。

Comment: Rubyを用いて書かれた処理が記述されています。

説明不足で申し訳ありません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascriptがどうこうというより、Railsのテンプレートを誤解されています。

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
$("#<%= id %> .button").click(function()
{
    if ("<%= id %>"== $(this).parents().attr("id") )
    {
        <% puts "クリック時のみ動作させたい処理" %>
    }
});
</script>
```

このテンプレート中に `<% %>` で書いたRubyのコードは、レンダリングの際に実行されるため、次のようなHTMLがブラウザに送られることになります。

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
$("#foo123 .button").click(function()
{
    if ("foo123"== $(this).parents().attr("id") )
    {
        クリック時のみ動作させたい処理
    }
});
</script>
```

レンダリング処理では単にテンプレートファイルに `<% %>` が現れたらそのコードを実行しているだけで、それがJavascriptコードの一部なのか、まして関数や if 文の中なのかということは考慮しませんから、このような挙動になります。

ボタンを押した時にRubyを実行したいとなると、コントローラの別アクションや別テンプレートにその処理を書いておき、Ajaxで呼び出す必要があるように思います。
<sub>（Railsでの具体的な方法については詳しくないので調べていただけると）</sub>

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
RailsでのJavascriptの処理について完全に誤解をしておりました。

一度設計を見なおして、Javascript側の処理だけで出来るように変更しようと思います。
ありがとうございました。